# Export/Inport png file Android Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, import, export

```
 var pngExporterx = new PngExporter { Width = 600, Height = 400, Background = OxyColors.White };
    pngExporterx.ExportToFile(plot2, "Assets/DCUnityOutput.png");

    var pngImage = LoadPNG("Assets/DCUnityOutput.png");
```

Could you please explain me - why is it working during the windows debugging and not working when I install an app on the mobile device?

The PNGExporter is from Oxyplot for winForms.

On my phone I've checked the storage data permission but nothing happened. Is there any difference about storing app data in Android/Windows? What would be the solution for exporting .png image and importing it again?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see **two** reasons why this wouldn't work in a build on Android:

**1**. The location you're saving it.

You're saving the image at *"Assets/DCUnityOutput.png"* but the *"Assets"* directory only exist on the Editor when the project is opened. Once it is built, the *"Assets"* directory is no longer there. Always save to the `Application.persistentDataPath` path.

**2**. The PngExporter plugin dependencies.

The The PngExporter plugin you're using depends on some WPF and WinForm API which are not supported on mobile devices. When using Unity, avoid using random C# libraries unless you're sure they don't depend on the WPF and WinForm API.

---

It's really easy to save and load images in Unity and no WPF and WinForm API is required.

**Save:**

```
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "images");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, "DCUnityOutput.png");
File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, pngImageByteArray);
```

**Load:**

```
byte[] pngImageByteArray = null;
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "images");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, "DCUnityOutput.png");
pngImageByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(tempPath);
```

**Create Textue2D from the png/jpeg byte array:**

```
Texture2D tempTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
tempTexture.LoadImage(pngImageByteArray);
```

**Export/Save the Texture2D as png:**

```
byte[] pngImageByteArray = tempTexture.EncodeToPNG();
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "images");
tempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, "DCUnityOutput.png");
File.WriteAllBytes(tempPath, pngImageByteArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me a lot. To be honest - I need to use oxyplot library, I haven't found any library for unity to create plots, so I used this one. The problem was about folders, as you mentioned. Anyway. Thank you once again, have a nice day! ;)